# console.log works but return doesn't

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, function, return-value, amazon-inspector

I've been racking my brains with this one for some time. When I try to "return" the value of an AWS API to pass it to another function, it comes back undefined. When I console log that value, it works fine. In this case the returned value is an array and I am trying to grab the first element and not the full list.

```
function a() {
    inspector.listAssessmentTemplates(function(err, data) {
        let rntVal = data.assessmentTemplateArns[0]
        console.log(rntVal) **//outputs the expected string** 
        return rntVal
    })
}

function b() {
    let one = a()
    console.log(`${one}`) **//output is undefined**

b()
```

Comment: `function(err, data) {..}` is a callback, it runs asynchronously

Comment: I'd also highly recommend that you start adding `;` too